# GridBagLayout creating very small panels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to set the layout of a JFrame to be a grid bag layout.  I want to to essentially look like 4 grids of equal size, but with the bottom 2 merged into one panel.  I am adding JPanels to each.  However, I get 3 small grids at the middle of the JFrame, not properly sized.  It looks like this instead.

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Hangman extends JPanel{
    private String word;
    private JPanel hA, gL, letters;

    public void setupLayout(JFrame window){
            window.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

            hA = new JPanel();
            hA.setBackground(Color.blue);
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 0;
            window.add(hA, c);

            gL = new JPanel();
            gL.setBackground(Color.green);
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 0;
            window.add(gL, c);

            letters = new JPanel();
            letters.setBackground(Color.black);
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            c.weightx = 1.0;
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 1;
            c.gridwidth = 2;
            window.add(letters, c);
    }
        public void startWindow(){
            JFrame window = new JFrame();
            Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            int screenHeight = (int) screenSize.getHeight();
            int windowHeight = (int) ((screenHeight / 4) * 3);
            window.setSize(windowHeight, windowHeight);
            window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setupLayout(window);
            window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void startGame(){
            Prep prepare = new Prep();
            word = prepare.findWord(true);
            startWindow();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
                Hangman start = new Hangman();
            start.startGame();
    }
}
```

It's not very important what Prep does.  It just takes a random word from a text file.  I couldn't see how it would affect the layout.  To recap, I need to make it so each of the 4 grid spaces span one fourth of the window, and then make the bottom 2 cells merged with a JPanel added to each of them.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
 I needed to set the weight of all of them to be 1.  It is solved.

Answer (score 2):

GridBagLayout displays each component at its preferred size. Since you didn't add any components to the panels you just see a small panel.

If you want the panels to fill the space available then you need to play with the constraints.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information and working examples. You will want to look at the "fill" and "weightx/weighty" constraints.

> and then make the bottom 2 cells merged

you will also need to look at the "gridwidth/gridheight" constraints.