# JFrame does not show anything before maximizing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to do a assignment for school in java. For some reason, when I run the program, it creates the Jframe in the resolution I specified but does not have anything in it. Only after I maximize it does it actually show the components I added.

Also, the maximized frame does show the components but still not in the layout I set.
Here is my code:

```
package Question2;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Fibb extends JFrame {
    public void makeFrame(){
        
        //setting frame attributes
        setSize(1200, 800);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        //making objrcts for everything
        GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        JLabel numsLabel = new JLabel("1st & 2nd Numbers");
        JLabel seqLen = new JLabel("Length of sequence");
        JTextField firstNums = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField sequenceLength = new JTextField(10);
        JButton generate = new JButton("Generate Sequence");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        
        //setting panel layout to "Grid bag"
        panel.setLayout(layout);
        
        // adding componets in the grid
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(numsLabel);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        panel.add(seqLen);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(firstNums);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        panel.add(sequenceLength);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        panel.add(generate);
        
        //frame to panel 
        add(panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fibb make = new Fibb();
        make.makeFrame();
    }
}
```

[What appears when I run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Vyig.png)
[After I maximize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl4aQ.png)

I have tried making the frame start maximized and changing around the resolutions but to no avail. I literally have no idea how to go about troubleshooting.

Comment: 1) Components need to be added to the frame BEFORE making the frame visible. 2) You are not using GridBagLayout correctly. You need to specify the constraints when adding the component to the panel. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). The tutorial will also  show how to better structure your code to follow Swing conventions.

Comment: Please see @camickr's answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16409678/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47609844/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54896803/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40198916/522444)

Comment: check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component)) of `Container.add()`, inherited by `JFrame`: "This method changes layout-related information, and therefore, invalidates the component hierarchy. If the container has already been displayed, the hierarchy must be validated thereafter in order to display the added component."